# Given a GapP function can I assume there is an "optimal" function that solves it?

Tags: complexity-theory

What I mean by this, is let $f \in GapP$, and let $k_n =min\{k|\forall x  (s.t. |x|<n):2^k > |f(x)|\}$ for every $n$, can I assume there is a nondetermenistic machine $M$ that on input $x$ does at most $k_n$ coin tosses with results in $\{0, 1\}$, and that for every $x$: $f(x)=\#(M(x)=1) - \#(M(x)=0)$, where $\#(M(x)=a)$ means the amount of passes of $M$ on input $x$ for which it returns $a$?

Comment: Generally the answer to most "can I assume...?" questions is, if you have to ask, no, it's best not to assume -- you should try to prove it yourself.  So, have you tried to prove it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a complete answer, but it is actually easy to show that if it were true then we'd get $AWPP ⊂ BPP$, so I guess no we can't assume this. To prove this, let $L \in AWPP$, then there are $f \in GapP$ and $g \in FP$ s.t.: $x\in L => 2/3<f(x)/g(1^{|x|})<1$ and $x\notin L => 0 <f(x)/g(1^{|x|})<1/3$, but becasue of the assumption we know there is a machine $M$, that does at most $log (g(1^{|x|}))$ coin tosses and satisfies $f(x)=\#(M(x)=1)-\#(M(x)=0)$, so that means that $2*Pr[M(x)=1]-1=f(x)/g(1^{|x|})$ and so that proves $L \in BPP$